# Are member variables like the characteristics of an object?

Tags: java, variables, object

As an analogy, I have learned that methods in an object represent the actions that can be taken by the object if it were in real life.

Taking this further, I concluded that member variables were equal to the characteristics said object would have. Would this analogy be correct?

For the following example, a Dog would be created with known characteristics of its hair color, shed rate, and speed, while having the ability to Bark if called upon by a different object.

```
public class Dog {
    public String mHairColor;
    public int mShedRate;
    public int mSpeed;

    public Bark {
        // example
    }
}
```

Comment: Your bark method doesn't have the correct syntax, but I see nothing wrong with your analogy

Comment: You tell me. Are those characteristics of each Dog? This seems kind of a common-sense kind of question.

Comment: yes member variables are characteristics of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member variables contain data that **defines the state of an object**. By comparison, **methods** define the actions an object can perform. Adding a member variable is equivalent to declaring that any instance of an object requires additional data in order to be complete.

For instance, adding another field (member or instance variable, all the same) to your class called "eyeColor" requires that all dogs have an eye color.

Moreover, all fields are **default initialized** with some value. For example, any field of type String will be initialized to "".

Answer (score 1):

Your bark method should be lower case. Second, it needs a return type, i.e. void, String, int, whatever...  As it stands now, it's syntax is that of the constructor, but the constructor for a class called Dog must be called Dog().  See below:

```
public class Dog {
    public String mHairColor;
    public int mShedRate;
    public int mSpeed;

    public Dog() {
        // example
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }


}
```

Comment: I think an additional comment should be made that the fields have some default values assigned to them